# Why does my WAMS query return the verbose name of its return type rather than a value from the table (should be null in this case)?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-8, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

This query:

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetSenderDeviceIDForSenderIDAndReaderDeviceID(string senderID, string readerDeviceID)
{
    IMobileServiceTable<PLATYPUS_WAMS_INVITATIONS> table = App.MobileService.GetTable<PLATYPUS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>();

    MobileServiceTableQuery<String> query =
        table.Where(i => i.SenderID == senderID).
              Where(i => i.ReaderDeviceID == readerDeviceID).
              Select(i => i.SenderDeviceID).
              Take(1); // the query returns a List, but I only want 1 record (and it should only return 1)
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

returns "*System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]*"

It should be null (in the particular test case I was running) and values such as "03-11-BA-22 " at other times.

Comment: I'm not sure what WAMS is, but when you get the string name of a `Task`, it's usually because your service host doesn't understand `async` methods and tries to serialize the `Task` object.

Comment: WAMS = Windows Azure Mobile Services. IOW, my service host is Microsoft Azure, so ... ???

Comment: what does your call to GetSenderDeviceId... look like?  As @Stephen said....  var f = GetSenderDeviceId...() will return the Task; var f = await GetSenderDeviceID will return the list

Comment: Right. By "service host", I meant like WCF or whatever calls `GetSenderDeviceIDForSenderIDAndReaderDeviceID`.

Comment: Okay, changing the call by prepending the "await" fixed it (after I thereafter re[factor,vamp]ed some other things. Thanks, both of you!